# IIdTextEncoding undeclared indentifier

Tags: delphi, installation, delphi-7, indy10

I uninstalled an old version of Indy and installed the newest version ([r5418](http://indy.fulgan.com/ZIP/)).

I followed the [instructions](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.EN.aspx) but when I compile the package IndyCoreX0.dpk I get an error in Idbuffer.pas: "undeclared indentifier: IIdTextEncoding".

What am I doing wrong? I have Delphi 7.

Comment: `IIdTextEncoding` is declared in the `IdGlobal` unit. The error means you did not fully uninstall the old version, the compiler found an older source file instead of the newer one. `IIdTextEncoding` did not exist yet when Indy was first shipped with Delphi 7 (in fact, it wasn't even Indy 10 yet back then), so make sure you are completely wiping out any old version. It is not enough to just remove the Indy package binaries from the IDE, make sure you remove old source files, old dcu/object files, etc. Make sure there are no old files left on the IDE/compiler search paths.

Comment: I removed all Indy related files and it worked.